# jquery function not called on click event

Tags: jquery, asp.net

```
$(function () 
{        
    $('#btnnext').click(function ()  
    {
    alert("Hello after click event");
    });
});
```

And the code for button as:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnnext" runat="server"  CssClass="BStyle" OnClick="btnnext_Click" Text="Save" />
```

I have place Button control in update panel control and also have used master.. page

Comment: @kis try to write script in update panel

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#<%=btnnext.ClientID%>').click(function ()  
    {
    alert("Hello after click event");
    });
```

Another way would be to use `OnClientClick` attribute

```
<asp:Button ID="btnnext" runat="server" CssClass="BStyle" OnClick="btnnext_Click" OnClientClick="MyFunctionName()" Text="Save" />

<script>
function MyFunctionName(){
    alert('test');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

You can Use `ClientID` to Get AcutalID Generated by ASP.net

```
$('<%#btnnext.ClientID%>').click(function ()  
    {
    alert("Hello after click event");
    });
```

Comment: The # is missing. try $('#<%=btnnext.ClientID%>')

Answer (score 1):

Look at what ASP.net generates (view source on your webpage).

ASP.NET webforms generate another ID for the frontend ID then what you are saying to asp:Button. my advice is to either bind the click on a cssClass instead or if you still want to bind it with an id you need to use `[id$="_btnnext"]` as a selector.

```
$(function () {
    $('[id$="_btnnext"]').click(function () {
        alert("Hello after click event");
    });
});
```

Comment: are you getting js errors? What have you tried, if you bind it on a class name instead it will work. Also what ID do you get when you view your source code in the browser?

Comment: it generates id as: ContentPlaceHolder1_btnnext

Comment: bind it with a CSS class instead on ID, because asp.net wont change that value. or as many pointed out `'#<%=btnnext.ClientID%>'`

Comment: That works. But is it right way to use CSS class instead of ID?

Comment: I dont understand what you mean with "The right way"? You can solve it easy with a css class because .NET wont change that, but if thats the only button on your site you could use button as a selector. I personally never bind anything with an ID, because I'm almost never have something that is that unique. So personally I would bind it with a css class yeah.

Comment: I have used that CSS class for all the button on the form...!

Comment: you can add another class in HTML `"BStyle btnnext"` and bind it with `.btnnext` instead

Comment: yeah, I also had did that. Thank Voigtan!

Answer (score 0):

You can use your button ID or your Css class as selector

ID selector

```
$('<%#btnnext.ClientID%>').click(function ()  
    {
    alert("Hello after click event");
    });
```

Class selector

```
$('.BStyle').click(function ()  
    {
    alert("Hello after click event");
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this, using `.on` function :

```
$(function() 
{        
  $('#btnnext').on('click',function()  
  {
    alert("Hello after click event");
  });
});
```

Comment: Have you ever tried to alert something rather than place in click handler like $(function() { alert('hello'); }); .Just wanna check jquery library is load or not. Because there is nothing wrong with the code right now.

Comment: Yeah, if i place alert before click event then it automatically alert on page load.